# Is it possible to use template arguments in virtual function in modern C++?

Tags: swift, templates, c++11, generics, architecture

I used to do C++ development several years ago and back then I found it difficult to combine template programming with OOP. Currently I program in Swift and I tried doing some of the things I struggled with then.

This Swift code will illustrate the problem:

```
// protocol is like Java interface or C++ pure virtual base class
protocol Log {

    // want to able to add elements from a collection of Ints, but
    // it should be any sort of collection that 
    // can be treated as a sequence
    func add<T: SequenceType where T.Generator.Element == Int>(values: T)
}

class DiscreteLog: Log {
    var vals: [Int] = []
    func add<T: SequenceType where T.Generator.Element == Int>(values: T) {
        for v in values {
            vals.append(v)
        }
    }

}

class ContinousLog: Log {
    var vals: [Double] = []

    func add<T: SequenceType where T.Generator.Element == Int>(values: T) {
        for v in values {
            vals.append(Double(v))
        }
    }
}

// I don't have to know whether the log is Continuous or Discrete
// I can still add elements to it
var log: Log = ContinousLog()
log.add([1, 2, 3])

// and elements can come from any kind of sequence, it does not need
// to be an array
log.add(["four": 4, "five: 5].values)
```

So the problem is that if the C++ code defined as as:

```
virtual void add(vector<Int> elements>)
```

Then sure I could have multiple subclasses implement this method, but I could never provide anything but vectors as arguments.

I could try changing it to something more generic using iterator:

```
virtual void add(vector<Int>::iterator elements>)
```

But I am still limited to using vector iterators. So I guess I would have to write something like:

```
template<typename Iterator>
virtual void add(Iterator elements>)
```

But that will give compile errors as template based arguments are not allowed for virtual methods.

Anyway I wondered if this sort of thing is possible in modern C++.

Answer (score 1):

C++ templates and C#/Swift/Java generics are different things.

They are both "pattern code" in a sense (they are patterns that generate code), but C#/Swift/Java generics use type erasure and "forget" almost everything about the types they work with, while C++ templates are elephants.  And elephants never forget.

It turns out that can make an elephant forget, but you have to tell it to.  The technique of "forgetting" about details of a type is known as "type erasure" or "run time concepts".

So you want to type erase down to the concept of "a sequence of integers".  You want to take any type, so long as it is a sequence of integers, and be able to iterate over it.  Seems fair.

`boost` has such type erasures.  But who wants to always rely on boost?

First, type erase an input iterator:

```
  template<class T>
  struct input_iterator:
    std::iterator<
      std::input_iterator_tag, // category
      T, // value
      std::ptrdiff_t, // distance
      T*, // pointer
      T // reference
    >
  {
    struct erase {
      virtual void advance() = 0;
      virtual erase* clone() const = 0;
      virtual T get() const = 0;
      virtual bool equal(erase const& o) = 0;
      virtual ~erase() {}
    };
    std::unique_ptr<erase> pimpl;
    input_iterator(input_iterator&&)=default;
    input_iterator& operator=(input_iterator&&)=default;
    input_iterator()=default;
    input_iterator& operator++() {
      pimpl->advance();
      return *this;
    }
    input_iterator operator++(int) {
      auto copy = *this;
      ++*this;
      return copy;
    }
    input_iterator(input_iterator const& o):
      pimpl(o.pimpl?o.pimpl->clone():nullptr)
    {}
    input_iterator& operator=(input_iterator const&o) {
      if (!o.pimpl) {
        if (pimpl) pimpl->reset();
        return *this;
      }
      pimpl = std::unique_ptr<erase>(o.pimpl->clone());
      return *this;
    }
    T operator*() const {
      return pimpl->get();
    }
    friend bool operator==( input_iterator const& lhs, input_iterator const& rhs ) {
      return lhs.pimpl->equal(*rhs.pimpl);
    }
    friend bool operator!=( input_iterator const& lhs, input_iterator const& rhs ) {
      return !(lhs==rhs);
    }
    template<class It>
    struct impl:erase{
      It it;
      impl(impl const&)=default;
      impl(It in):it(std::move(in)){}
      virtual void advance() override { ++it; }
      virtual erase* clone() const override { return new impl(*this); }
      virtual T get() const override { return *it; }
      virtual bool equal(erase const& o) override {
        return static_cast<impl const&>(o).it == it;
      }
    };

    template<
      class It,
      class=std::enable_if<
        std::is_convertible<
          typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference,
          T
        >{}
      >
    >
    input_iterator(It it):pimpl( new impl<It>{it} ) {}
  }; // input_iterator
```

Next, have a range template.  This is a container that stores non-type erased iterators, and exposes enough to iterate over those iterators.

```
 template<class It>
 struct range {
   It b; It e;
   It begin() const { return b; }
   It end() const { return e; }

   range() = default;

   range(It start, It finish):b(std::move(start)),e(std::move(finish)) {};

   range(range&&)=default;
   range(range const&)=default;
   range& operator=(range&&)=default;
   range& operator=(range const&)=default;

   template<class R,
     class R_It=std::decay_t<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<R>()))>,
     class=std::enable_if< std::is_convertible<R_It, It>{} >
   >
   range( R&& r ):
     range(std::begin(r), std::end(r))
   {} // TODO: enable ADL begin lookup
 };
```

The above type is really basic: C++1z has better ones, as does `boost`, as do I have in my own code base.  But it is enough to handle `for(:)` loops, and implicit conversion from containers with compatible iterators.

Finally our sequence type:

```
template<class T>
using sequence_of = range<input_iterator<T>>;
```

Wait, that's it?  Nice, those types compose well!

And barring errors, we are done.

Your code now would take a `sequence_of<int>`, and they could pass a `std::vector<int>` or `std::list<int>` or whatever.

The input_iterator type-erasure type-erases any iterator down to getting a `T` via `*`, `==`, copy, and `++` advance, which is enough for a `for(:)` loop.

The `range<input_iterator<int>>` will accept any iterable range (including containers) whose iterators can be converted to an `input_iterator<int>`.

The downside?  We just introduced a bunch of overhead.  Each method goes through virtual dispatch, from `++` to `*` to `==`.

This is (roughly) what generics do -- they type-erase down to the requirements you give it in the generic clause.  This means they are working with abstract objects, not concrete objects, so they unavoidably suffer performance penalties of this indirection.

C++ templates can be used to generate type erasure, and there are even tools (boost has some) to make it easier.  What I did above is a half-assed manual one.  Similar techniques are used in `std::function<R(Args...)>`, which type-erases down to (conceptually) {copy, call with (Args...) returning R, destroy} (plus some incidentals).

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52c898374e5d7cfd).

(The code above freely uses C++14.)

So the C++ equivalent `Log` is:

```
struct Log {
  virtual void add(sequence_of<int>) = 0;
  virtual ~Log() {}
};
```

Now, the type erasure code above is a bit ugly.  To be fair, I just implemented a language feature in C++ without direct language support for it.

I've seen some proposals to make type erasure easier in C++.  I do not know the status of those proposals.

---

If you want to do your own, here is an "easy" way to do type erasure in 3 steps:

First, determine what operations you want to erase.  Write the equivalent of `input_iterator<T>` -- give it a bunch of methods and operators that do what you want.  Be sparse.  Call this the "external type".  Ideally *nothing* in this type is `virtual`, and it should be a Regular or Semi-regular type (ie, it should behave value-like, or move-only-value-like).  Don't implement anything but the interface yet.

Second, write an inner class `erase`.  It provides a pure-virtual interface to a set of functions that could provide what you need in your external type.

Store a `unique_ptr<erase> pimpl;` within the external type.  Forward the methods you expose in the external type to the `pimpl;`.

Third, write an inner `template<class X> class impl<X>:erase`.  It stores a variable `X x;`, and it implements everything in `erase` by interacting with `X`.  It should be constructable from an `X` (with optional perfect forwarding).

You then create a perfect forwarding constructor for the external type that creates its `pimpl` via a `new impl<X>(whatever)`.  Ideally it should check that its argument is a valid one via SFINAE techniques, but that is just a qualify of implementation issue.

Now the external type "erases" the type of any object it is constructed from "down to" the operations you exposed.

---

Now, for your actual problem, I'd write `array_view` or steal `std::experimental::array_view`, and restrict my input to be any kind of contiguous buffer of data of that type.  This is more performant, and accepting any sequence is over engineering unless you really need it.